# Why operators '/' and 'div' in Z3 give different results?

Tags: z3

I was trying to represent a real number with two integer numbers as using them as the numerator and the denominator of the real number. I wrote the following program:

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const f Real)

(assert (= f (/ a b)))
(assert (= f 0.5))
(assert (> b 2))
(assert (> b a))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The program returned SAT result as follows:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun f () Real
    (/ 1.0 2.0))
  (define-fun b () Int
    4)
  (define-fun a () Int
    2)
)
```

However, if I write '(assert (= f (div a b)))' instead of '(assert (= f (/ a b)))', then the result is UNSAT. Why does not div return the same result?

Moreover, and the main concern for me, I did not find a way to use operator '/' in z3 .Net API. I can see only function MkDiv, which actually for operator 'div'. Is there a way so that I can apply operator '/' in the case of z3 .Net API? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking neither of these formulas is SMT-LIB2 compliant, because `/` is a function that takes two Real inputs and produces a Real output, whereas `div` is a function that takes two Int inputs and produces an Int (see [SMT-LIB Theories](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories.shtml)). Z3 is more relaxed and automatically converts those objects. If we enable the option `smtlib2_compliant=true` then it will indeed report an error in both cases.

The reason for the `div` version being unsatisfiable is that there is indeed no solution where `f`  is an integer according to `(= f (/ a b))`, but there is indeed no integer that satisfies `(= f 0.5)`