# Z3 C api : multidimensional array type variable cause invalid result

Tags: z3

here is the Z3 context:

```
    (forall ((X (Array Int (Array Int Real))) (i Int) (j Int))
     (let ((a!1 (* (- 1) (to_int (select (select X i) j)))))
        (= (+ (testArr X i j) a!1) 0))))
```

this means:

```
forall X,i,j. testArr(X,i,j) == X[i][j]
```

now, i try to prove two similar assert:

```
 1 (=> (= (select (select Z i1) j1) (select (select X i) j))
       (= (select (select Z i1) j1)  (testArr X i j)))
```

and

```
 2 (=> (= v (select (select X i) j))
       (= v (to_real (testArr X i j))))
```

the second assert Z3 return valid, but the 1st assert Z3 return invalid,and in other example Z3 sometimes return unknown.
**why??**

Comment: Could you add the whole problem file? It's not clear whether all the undeclared variables (X, Z, i1, v) are unquantified or universal. Also, is there a definition of testArr or are you asking Z3 to come up with a new function definition?

Comment: Thanks for your help.I just solved this problem. The cause of this problem is  type mismatch. The return type of testArr is integer,but the type of X[i][j] is real, so Z3 add to_int or to_real automatically.When I change the return type of function testArr to real.Z3 return valid.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting us know! By default Z3 will indeed convert between ints and reals which can be confusing. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027628/why-operators-and-div-in-z3-give-different-results/26037156#26037156